# How to add double elements to RList?

Tags: java, r, rserve

I tried to call R by Rserve using Java code. I wanted to use REXPGenericVector to store and pass an array to R:

```
RList r = new RList();
r.add(new Double(1.0));
REXPGenericVector v = new REXPGenericVector(r);

// make a new local connection on default port (6311)
RConnection c = new RConnection();
// assign data to variable x
c.assign("x",v);

System.out.println("Printing out v:"+v);
```

However, an error message shows up at `c.assign("x",v);`:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to org.rosuda.REngine.REXP
at org.rosuda.REngine.RList.at(RList.java:103)
at org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.protocol.REXPFactory.getBinaryLength(REXPFactory.java:489)
at org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RConnection.assign(RConnection.java:272)
at com.xypress.Test.main(Test.java:29)
```

How can I add double or string or other type of data to RList?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have no experience with `rserve`, but based off the documentation,it looks like you're doing everything correctly. Either I'm missing something or there is more to the problem than the posted code...Again, I am unfamiliar with this library, but the only thing that I can think of is that for whatever reason, `REXPGenericVector` is not working (as expected with a `Double`).  Perhaps you should try another `REXP`?

Answer (score 1):

i ran in the same trap!
Just try the class REXPDouble, instead of Double.

For example:
double doubleValue = 1.0;
r.add(new REXPDouble(doubleValue));

that should work.

If you like to know more look at this web page: http://icbtools.med.cornell.edu/javadocs/Rserve/org/rosuda/REngine/REXPDouble.html

Answer (score 0):

I too ran into the same issue, and found this test class: https://github.com/s-u/REngine/blob/master/Rserve/src/test/java/org/rosuda/rserve/RserveTest.java

It demonstrates how to pass values to R, and retrieve the results back from the evaluation. I found this helpful, specially when dealing with lists and vectors.